# How to decrease the width between bars in lattice bar chart?

Tags: r, bar-chart, lattice

I am using following code to generate 10 bar charts side by side.

```
   library(reshape2)
   library(lattice) 

   data <- read.csv("/Users/.../data.csv", sep = ",") 
   df.long<-melt(data,id.vars=c("Vis","Task"))
   df.long

   barchart(Vis~value|Task,
         groups=Vis,data=df.long,layout=c(5,2),
         between = list(y=0.2),
         auto.key = list(rectangles = TRUE, space = 'top', columns = 5), 
         origin = 0,
         par.settings = list(fontsize=list(text=8) ),
         box.ratio = 1/4,
         box.width = 1
    )
```

Here is my data in csv format.

```
Vis,Accuracy,Task
Bar chart,66,Anomalies
Line chart,52,Anomalies
Pie chart,80,Anomalies
Scatterplot,52,Anomalies
Table,66,Anomalies
Bar chart,100,Cluster
Line chart,33,Cluster
Pie chart,100,Cluster
Scatterplot,60,Cluster
Table,93,Cluster
Bar chart,90,Correlation
Line chart,30,Correlation
Pie chart,40,Correlation
Scatterplot,80,Correlation
Table,70,Correlation
Bar chart,73,Derived
Line chart,80,Derived
Pie chart,66,Derived
Scatterplot,86,Derived
Table,100,Derived
Bar chart,46,Distribution
Line chart,60,Distribution
Pie chart,60,Distribution
Scatterplot,73,Distribution
Table,46,Distribution
Bar chart,100,Extremum
Line chart,77.7,Extremum
Pie chart,94,Extremum
Scatterplot,61,Extremum
Table,88.8,Extremum
Bar chart,100,Filter
Line chart,75,Filter
Pie chart,100,Filter
Scatterplot,83,Filter
Table,83,Filter
Bar chart,75,Order
Line chart,66,Order
Pie chart,50,Order
Scatterplot,58,Order
Table,59,Order
Bar chart,40,Range
Line chart,66.6,Range
Pie chart,100,Range
Scatterplot,93,Range
Table,93,Range
Bar chart,91,Retrieve
Line chart,66,Retrieve
Pie chart,100,Retrieve
Scatterplot,75,Retrieve
Table,100,Retrieve
```

I generate the following visualization but the distance between bars is really high. How can I decrease the width?

[image]

Comment: It easier to help if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample data in the question. We cannot load your local data to test.

Comment: @MrFlick I added the data above. I would appreciate if you could help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `Vis` both as the y variable and the grouping variable. This does not work very well in lattice. The easiest fix would probably just make a stacked barplot.

```
barchart(Vis~value|Task,
    groups=Vis,
    stack=T,
    data=df.long,
    layout=c(5,2),
    auto.key = list(rectangles = TRUE, space = 'top', columns = 5), 
    origin = 0,
    par.settings = list(fontsize=list(text=8) )
)
```

[image]

you could also remove Vis from the y-axis you are basically double labeling it the with color legend.

```
barchart(~value|Task,
    groups=Vis,
    data=df.long,
    layout=c(5,2),
    auto.key = list(rectangles = TRUE, space = 'top', columns = 5), 
    origin = 0,
    par.settings = list(fontsize=list(text=8) )
)
```

[image]

This is kind of a weakness of the lattice plotting system. You can do something like this with ggplot a bit more easily

library(ggplot2)

```
ggplot(df.long, aes(Vis, value, fill=Vis)) + 
    geom_bar(stat='identity') +
    coord_flip() + facet_wrap(~Task, ncol=5) +
    theme(legend.position="top") + 
    scale_fill_discrete(name="")
```

[image]